# Airplay: Playing a Movie from MPMoviePlayerController results in only audio being streamed to Apple tv

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation

Setting up Airplay was easy enough.

```
 self.moviePlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease];
 [self.moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:YES];
```

However, when I try to play a video, only the audio is streamed. The video continues to play on the iPad.
Additionally, the Airplay control only shows the "Audio Only" icon in the source list. (see photo).

[image]

This makes me think that iOS "thinks" that only audio is playing.
I have several other apps with Airplay on my device and they work correctly. I have cycled both the Apple tv and the iPad on and off. Both the iPad and the Apple tv have the latest OS installed. The video is being progressively downloaded, but it plays perfectly on the iPad.
Any ideas?

Comment: Would progressively downloaded content be streamed via AirPlay as well or is that possibly the show-stopper?

Comment: I see various reports on the web saying you may need to do a hard reboot of the device and that you may also get better results with an Airport express if you're not using one already.

I have exactly the same frustration as I find ONLY Apple approved apps (Youtube etc) are working for my setup whilst my own apps that correctly enable airplay result in seeing the speakers as per your Question. 

My gut feeling is that there is something Apple aren't telling us all yet - I thought it was fussy about the video encoding but my experiments with that have so far not changed anything.

Comment: @Till Progressively streamed content is listed as supported in the iOS Programming Guide.

Comment: @Roger I am using an Airport Extreme (newest rev) and have done reboots all around. I am also thinking that the encoding has something to do with this. But like you said, I haven't seen any restrictions. And I find it strange that the iPad could play content that the Apple tv could not.

Comment: @Corey thanks for double-checking and letting us know - then I also guess its an encoding issue. Last resort: analyze properly streamable content and find the one or two bits that make it work.

Comment: what is the format of your video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the unattractive answer is that iOS 5 solves these issues.

I have found that certain combinations of OSs and devices cause this issue: specifically iOS 4 with an iPhone 4.

So if you are having problems, install iOS 5. As of this post, there was a recent article quoting an Apple statement announcing that iOS 5 has a penetration of about 30% of eligible devices (3Gs and above). Since it has only been 1 week since its release, I am less concerned about solving the edge cases like the one I have stated above.

This was clearly a bug in the iOS 4 version of Airplay, and it is unlikely that the iOS 4 version will be updated to fix the bug at this point. So I am calling it case closed for now.

Answer (score 0):

Airplay [Supported formats](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010567-SW2) include (via Apple):

- H.264 video with AAC audio HTTP
- streaming, both live and on demand
- progressive download content
- local content

For web-based content, you can enable AirPlay Video in the QuickTime Plug-in or HTML5 video element as follows:

QTPlug-in:

```
airplay="allow"
airplay="deny" (Default)
For example: <embed src="movie.mov" width="320" height="240" airplay="allow">
```

HTML5 video element:

```
x-webkit-airplay="allow"
x-webkit-airplay="deny" (Default)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the iOS in use is 4.3 or later. 4.2.x did respond to the -setAllowsAirPlay call, but it really didn't work properly. 4.3 is the iOS version that officially supports AirPlay. I saw this audio-only bug when testing with 4.2.x devices.