# MPMoviePlayerController hide AirPlay button

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, airplay

I need to hide AirPlay button in my `MPMoviePlayerController` even when full mirroring is turned ON. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To hide AirPlay button of the `MPMoviePlayerController` set `allowsAirPlay` property to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the AirPlay icon, you'll need to either set the control to `MPMovieControlStyleNone` or write your own player.  (also see: [Disable AirPlay with MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749770/disable-airplay-with-mpmovieplayercontroller))