# Setting allows airplay to no still sends sound over airplay

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller, airplay

I am working with a media player, some media does not have the right to be played over Airplay, don't ask why :). So when I get that media, I set

```
movieplayerController.allowsAirplay = NO;
```

If you were playing with airplay before, it is then on by default next time. By doing the code above, you will get the movie playing on your device, but the sound audio route is still sent over airplay. I have tried to overwrite the audio route, but it doesn't budge, seems like Airplay trumps all.

If I could just disable airplay, my problem would be solved, but I can't find anywhere a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749770/disable-airplay-with-mpmovieplayercontroller) question. The answer mentions that the AirPlay button should always be visible to send audio.